# What's the difference between Apache's Mesos infrastructure and Virtual Machine Cluster

Tags: virtual-machine, mesos

What exactly is the difference between Apache's Mesos and Virtual Machine Cluster? I understand both are server cluster management software. Can anyone elaborate where the main differences?
Is it possible to run Mesos on VM Cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to run Mesos on VM Cluster?

Yes

Mesos and Virtual Machine Cluster are similar but Mesos is more generic then VM Cluster. Mesos is mostly for scheduling the work on machines. It doesn't care what machine or what type of **workload**. So in theory Mesos can schedule **VMs** while VM Cluster only schedules VMs.